# Reading POP3 email with BeginReceive goes wrong with special characters

Tags: c#, sockets, pop3, beginreceive

I'm using the `BeginReceive` from `Socket` to receiving data from a e-mail.

I create  a `StringBuilder` to put in the last position of the BeginReceive method, in `object state`

It works but `StringBuilder` was with strange characters. Instead of a basic portuguese name,  who is in email (**João Gelásio**), it appears **Jo=E3o Gel=E1sio**

I can't understand if the problem is with `StringBuilder` configuration or I need to do some trick when reading the email with `BeginReceive`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> It works but StringBuilder was with strange characters. Instead of a basic portuguese name, who is in email (João Gelásio), it appears Jo=E3o Gel=E1sio

That looks like it's just a matter of the text being in [quoted printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. There should be headers specifying this.

Note that it has nothing to do with whether you're using async or synchronous APIs.

Ideally, use a dedicated mail API to handle POP3 instead of writing your own low-level handlers. It should cover all of this for you.

Comment: I'm using a mail API to do this, but I thnink this is not cover. When I see the mail in mailbox everything is ok.

Comment: @Gelásio: If you're talking directly to the socket, that's really *not* using a mail API... or if it is, it's an insanely thin one. Yes, I'd expect it to be fine in the mailbox - because the mail client understands the protocol (including quoted printable) correctly.

Comment: I'm using this: http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=7T61R6FGAWR5AG6AM1VETW6K1A&s=socket

Comment: @Gelásio: So why are you handling the socket directly? Does the API not do all of that for you? On a glance at it, it looks like it should be able to do all the parsing for you.

Comment: I'm just follow the code (debugging) to try find the problem and I stuck here in StartReceive method http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid0DABE2CB1FF7EDA1F5992642ABE4F28A1A5964D7.aspx?s=socket#L5 I have this exacte code

Comment: @Gelásio: That just shows it's not a good mail API, basically. I suggest you find a better one.